# Loading an angular component using a short key

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a requirement to use a short key to load an angular component.

The short key i want to use for this purpose is "."

If period is pressed when the angular component is loaded, then on click of the "." character i want to load the angular component.

However, I want to make sure that the angular component is not fired when I am on a form field entering any value.

In short the keypress should only be fired when not active on any specific form field. What condition should i check to ensure that while the key is pressed the user is not active on any of the form fields of that component.

Following is the code that I have to listen to the keydown event and identifies the key that was pressed.

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
alert('Key pressed was :::: ' + (event.key === "."))
alert('Key was pressed');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could check that the user is pressing period when the target is `body`, so you can try the following:

```ts
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (event.key === "." && ((event.target as HTMLElement).tagName === "BODY")) {
    alert('period pressed outside fields!')
  }
}
```

**DEMO:** [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfgsmc)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if(event.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    console.log('input clicked');
    return;
  }

  console.log('Key pressed was :::: ' + (event.key === "."))
  console.log('Key was pressed');
}
```